# how to make auto-scroll after a click in react

Tags: reactjs, scroll, auto, siblings, refer

What I need is that after clicking one of the labels in the Header component it scrolls me directly to that component

here is my Home page that contains my main components

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Header/>
      <Menu/>
      <Holder/>
      <Flyer/>
      <SideBar/>
      <Steps/>
      <Contact/>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

and here is my Header component

```
const Menu = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="Menu-Popup-Container">
        <div className="Menu-Popup">
          <div className="Menu-Block l1-s-menu">
            <label>Contact us</label>
          </div>
          <div className="Menu-Block l1-s-menu">
            <label>Menu</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Welcome</label>
          </div>

          <div className="Menu-Block l1-s-menu">
            <label>How to buy</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export { Menu };
```

do you know if i could refer external components like siblings?